# Sharing wordpress website on facebook shows root primary domain name, not site URL

Tags: facebook, wordpress, url, meta

When I post my wordpress-site URL in a status update on facebook, the primary domain URL where content is being hosted shows up and not the actual URL for the site.

Visit http://www.indicamarketing.com, and post in status update to see what I mean.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've tried a few different ogg and meta descriptions in the head, but none seem to work :(

**
[image: primary domain in status update]

Comment: Hi, did you resolve this problem ? I got the same now...
was the dns table for your hoster is the problem? the A,CNAME,..and other info ..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your canonical URL is not well set.

Try setting this to your url:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://yoururl.com"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed to use the debugger on Facebook to solve the problem.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: And if this solved your issue, please do accept it as solution, so people in future might be helped.